# gedit scroll area stops short of the screen - am I missing something?

Tags: gedit, scrollbar

I'm using gedit 2.30.3 .  Even when the window is maximized, if I put the cursor all the way to the right to the scrollbar area and click to move up or down a screenfull of text, it won't do it!  It's like gedit allocates a pixel at the extreme right just to annoy me! I have to carefully position the cursor in the scroll area.  What is going on and how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [documented bug about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/206837).

Three methods of dealing with it that I know of:

- Live without scrolling by page the way you would like to or are used to.
- Workaround by using a different method of scrolling full pages (e.g. PgUp/PgDn keys, assigning some modifier key to make scrollwheel scrolling go by page, etc.)
- Following some of the links and linked bugs in that page I found someone suggested using the xrandr program to fool the computer into stopping his mouse just short of the edge.  This was mentioned in [comment 10 of bug 206837](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/206837/comments/10).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I'm glad to see that it's being looked at, although the pace is kind of slow... I think it certainly fits the definition of a "papercut".

Comment: BTW, this does not seem to be a problem using Gedit in Unity Ubuntu 14.04. Can't say what's going on in Xubuntu, though.